# Can I display EPCalendar in a container rather than full screen?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

Hi and thanks in advance to anyone who is able to help me.
I am working with EPCalendarPicker (A swift calendar library) and I am wondering if I am able to show the calendar in a container instead of how it currently opens full screen over my other content.

```
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: calendarPicker)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out a way to do so:

```
calendarPicker = EPCalendarPicker(startYear: currentYear, endYear: currentYear+2, multiSelection: false, selectedDates: [date!])
                calendarPicker.calendarDelegate = self // so the delegate methods work
                calendarViewer.addSubview(calendarPicker.view) // instead of presenting as a new VC, add the calendar picker view to your own custom view 
                calendarPicker.view.frame = calendarViewer.bounds // set the frame to the container's bounds
```

And you are good to go. Hope this helps

Comment: Giggs I: crash my app reason: 'UICollectionView dataSource is not set'